# How to make a timer using javascript such that it creates a div element for displaying the time on javascript execution

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to make this timer webpage which displays the seconds decreasing when the initial seconds is inputted. I am firstly running a function which creates a h2 element and then prints out the initial value inputted. I then use setInterval to execute a function which reduces the value of the h2 element by 1 till it reaches zero. Once it reached 0, I use clearInterval to end it. For some reason it takes too long to execute and the webpage crashes without outputting anything on the screen. I do not understand where the execution is taking too long, please do help me out. Any other way this can be done? Here is the code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TIMER</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Enter the number of seconds for the timer <input id='initial' type="text">
    </label> <br>

    Press the button to start the timer <br>
    <button id="start_timer">Timer</button> <br><br>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var timerValue=document.getElementById('initial');
        var buttonEl=document.getElementById("start_timer");

        function reduceTime(){
            countDown.textContent=parseFloat(countDown.textContent)-1;
        }

        function initial(){
            countDown=document.createElement('h2')
            countDown.textContent=timerValue.value;
            while(parseFloat(countDown.textContent)>0){
                timer=window.setInterval(reduceTime,1000);
            }
            if(parseFloat(countDown.textContent)===0){
                window.clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }
        buttonEl.addEventListener('click',initial);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Append your new `h2` element to the DOM, move the test for `clearInterval` in `reduceTime()` and remove the `while` loop for `setInterval`:

```js
var timerValue = document.getElementById('initial');
var buttonEl = document.getElementById("start_timer");

function reduceTime() {
  if (parseFloat(countDown.textContent) === 0) {
    window.clearInterval(timer);
  } else {
    countDown.textContent = parseFloat(countDown.textContent) - 1;
  }
}

function initial() {
  countDown = document.createElement('h2');
  document.body.appendChild(countDown)
  countDown.textContent = timerValue.value;
  timer = window.setInterval(reduceTime, 1000);

}
buttonEl.addEventListener('click', initial);
```

```html
<label>Enter the number of seconds for the timer <input id='initial' type="text">
    </label> <br> Press the button to start the timer <br>
<button id="start_timer">Timer</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. Is it necessary to append the child using appendChild()? Why wouldn't it work with it?

Comment: The new element must not only be created with `createElement` but also inserted (or appended) into the dom with the `appendChild` or `insertBefore` methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SLePort

Answer (score 0):

The problem was when you in `while` cycle added new intervals when the condition stayed the same during 1 second. Also you did nothing with variable `countDown`. Here is a fix:

```js
var timerValue=document.getElementById('initial');
var buttonEl=document.getElementById("start_timer");
var countDown = document.getElementById("countDown");
var timer;

function reduceTime(){
    var time = parseFloat(countDown.textContent)-1;
    if (time < 0) {
      clearInterval (timer);
      return;
    }
    countDown.textContent=time;
}

function initial(){
    countDown.textContent=timerValue.value;
    timer = window.setInterval(reduceTime,1000);
}
buttonEl.addEventListener('click',initial);
```

```html
<label>
  Enter the number of seconds for the timer <input id='initial' type="text">
</label> 
<br />

Press the button to start the timer <br>
<button id="start_timer">Timer</button> <br><br>
 
<p>
  <h2 id="countDown"></h2>
</p>
```

Comment: I understand this method, but I specifically want to create the h2 element on the click of the button using document.createElement("h2")